# Sufficient conditions for limit exchanges in single-variable calculus

Tags: calculus, analysis

I was trying to prove that:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x} = 1$$

Using the following definition of $e$:
$$e = \lim_{h \to 0}(1+h)^\frac{1}{h}$$

We can rewrite the initial limit as:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\lim_{h \to 0}(1+h)^\frac{1}{h})^x - 1}{x}$$

If we "ignore" the internal limit (I don't know how to say this formally), this problem is easy:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\big((1+x)^\frac{1}{x} \big)^x - 1}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} (1 + x - 1) \frac{1}{x} = 1$$

My question is about this exchange:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\lim_{h \to 0}(1+h)^\frac{1}{h})^x - 1}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\big((1+x)^\frac{1}{x} \big)^x - 1}{x}$$

I am not sure if this is correct or not. I now this isn't valid for every case, so is there a way for me to know when this operation is valid or not? I was trying to find a theorem/explanation about this, but I wasn't able to describe this operation in words.

**EDIT:** Sorry if this isn't clear, my question is just about the limit exchange, I want to know if the operation I used is valid or not, the initial statement is just my motivation to ask this question.

Comment: Was it suggested to use that definition, or would you consider using a sum-type definition?

Comment: Hi: I don't know what it's called what you're doing but if you use L'Hopital's rule instead of your approach, it becomes a lot easier. Just take derivative of the top and bottom functions and then take the limit of that.

Comment: I don't have to prove using this definition, but I just want to know if what I did is a valid operation, and when I can't "transform" a limit of limits in just one limit.

Comment: What definition do you use for $e^x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not really "exchanging" limits, but specializing a two variable limit to a single variable one: the formula

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\lim_{h \to 0}(1+h)^\frac{1}{h})^x - 1}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\big((1+h)^\frac{1}{h} \big)^x - 1}{x}$$
has two variables, so we can think of this as an iterated limit. That is, we are doing some multi-variable calculus.

To do this rigorously, we need to be careful about convergence when we interchange limits. **BUT** if we just want to see why things worked out, I'll just assert that everything converges and manipulate the limits. We can thus view it as a multi-variable limit
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\big((1+h)^\frac{1}{h} \big)^x - 1}{x}=\lim_{(x,h)\to (0,0)} \frac{\big((1+h)^\frac{1}{h} \big)^x - 1}{x}. $$

This second integral is more complicated: its definition requires convergence along **all possible paths** as $(x,h)$ approach $(0,0)$ in the $(x,h)$-plane. Taking this convergence for granted (for the purpose of seeing what's going on), we can then compute the limit by **choosing a convenient path,** such as approaching $(0,0)$ along the diagonal line $x=h$. That is, just compute
$$\lim_{(x,h)\to (0,0)} \frac{\big((1+h)^\frac{1}{h} \big)^x - 1}{x}=\lim_{x=h\to 0} \frac{\big((1+x)^\frac{1}{x} \big)^x - 1}{x},$$
which is what you did.

The upshot is: this operation is not a valid trick unless you justify what you are doing with the two-variable limit.

Comment: Thanks! If the limit of all possible paths doesn't exist, is there a way to show that two paths are equivalents without evaluating both of them?

Comment: I don’t know if anything like that. You have to know something about the limit in order to compare limits along different paths.